# Set parent category of a newly created voice channel in a discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I'm writing a discord bot in python which creates voice channels. Right now the bot can create new voice channels but they appear at the top of the server, outside the categories. How do I set the parent of the channel when I create it, or move it after? I've attached what I have so far.

```
parent = after.voice.voice_channel.parent 
new_channel = await client.create_channel(after.server,after.voice.voice_channel.name, type=discord.ChannelType.voice)
```